# Change the order of integration $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{0}^{1-\sqrt{x+y}} f(x,y,z)\mathrm{dz}\mathrm{dy}\mathrm{dx}$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Change the order of integration of
>   $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{0}^{1-\sqrt{x+y}} f(x,y,z)dzdydx$$

**Answer:**

Here ,

$ 0 \leq z \leq 1-\sqrt{x+y} \\ 0 \leq y \leq 1-x \\ 0 \leq x \leq 1   $

Then the new integral is

$ \ \large \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-y} \int_{0}^{x-(1-z)^2} f(x,y,z) \ dydxdz \ $

**Am I right ?**

Help me out

Comment: No. When $dy$ in internal integral was taken we can't have a $1-y$ in middle integral bound!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{(1-z)^2}\int _0^{(1-z)^2-x}f(x,y,z)\mathrm{dy}\mathrm{dx}\mathrm{dz}$$

Answer (score 2):

$ \ \large \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x} \int_{0}^{1-\sqrt{x+y}} f(x,y,z) \ dzdydx \  = \large \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{(1-z)^2} \int_{0}^{(1-z)^2-x} f(x,y,z) \ dydxdz \ $